# Why is my responsive sidebar not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive sidebar using HTML, CSS, and JS. I want the sidebar to be hidden when the window width is a maximum of 1231px and have to click on the toggle button in order to see the sidebar. However, the code is not working correctly.

```js
let toggleSideBarBtn = document.getElementById("toggleSideBarBtn")
  toggleSideBarBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar")
    sidebar.classList.contains("d-none") ? sidebar.classList.remove("d-none") : sidebar.classList.add("d-none")
    console.log(sidebar)
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.containerMain {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 0;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}


.togglesidebar {}

.bodyContainer {
  padding: 50px;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1231px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="containerMain">
  <div class="sidebarContainer">
    <button class="togglesidebar" id="toggleSideBarBtn">
      toggle
    </button>
    <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyContainer">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui dignissimos exercitationem temporibus quis tempore dolores debitis? Facere saepe, debitis aperiam eos dicta a architecto vitae maxime tempora veritatis quo voluptatibus amet sunt nihil perferendis ipsum reiciendis ipsam? Atque quia veniam possimus veritatis, dolores maiores eveniet quas eum ut, voluptatum, doloribus eos! Sit fugit magnam deleniti rem similique delectus. Reiciendis, dolorem? Qui vitae quibusdam iusto similique quos voluptatem dicta minus ea, hic esse fuga asperiores, consequuntur nihil. Temporibus ab veniam esse, cum fugit alias maiores quos hic rerum blanditiis accusamus magnam corporis nisi iure recusandae. Explicabo nulla nostrum dolorem dolorum adipisci natus suscipit cupiditate sunt magni eveniet delectus magnam repellat perferendis ipsum ab minus tempore doloremque amet neque voluptatibus provident sequi, deserunt beatae. Quae quod natus distinctio temporibus, veritatis, obcaecati harum nemo aspernatur modi provident libero quas dignissimos earum eligendi laudantium est quo perspiciatis sit nisi necessitatibus! Consectetur ducimus blanditiis quae nostrum omnis repellendus, ullam provident, modi, facilis exercitationem impedit corporis perspiciatis. Maiores quidem aliquam amet nulla sit debitis quo fugiat. Dolor, neque minima. Amet fugit nisi nulla consectetur, praesentium aspernatur ipsa possimus optio, illum, ducimus nihil esse dolores vitae laboriosam voluptatum? Veritatis dolor pariatur recusandae quisquam, neque corporis quidem doloremque numquam eius voluptatum! Reiciendis rem, fugit eum facere, voluptas fuga dolor mollitia saepe commodi sint eligendi dolore repellendus sunt necessitatibus minus? Voluptas, itaque culpa, aliquam nesciunt dicta exercitationem incidunt eveniet omnis harum est mollitia non eaque minima obcaecati ex fugiat ab architecto officiis doloremque! Optio ipsum, culpa maxime mollitia sapiente sequi nisi necessitatibus harum aut atque vel ullam totam quis ex vitae porro pariatur placeat itaque tenetur voluptatum explicabo autem delectus!
    Voluptatum perferendis suscipit fugit ea optio porro ratione. Officia exercitationem, voluptas nihil laudantium quidem rerum dignissimos iste amet non minima odio nesciunt tempore quam ullam accusamus eius dolore delectus ducimus? Alias eaque vitae sit blanditiis magnam earum, adipisci deserunt deleniti optio, quasi, est modi repellendus similique mollitia architecto sequi? Culpa praesentium exercitationem quisquam, ipsam, commodi sunt facere autem magni, aut architecto sequi veniam dignissimos. Possimus rerum, molestias dicta hic numquam, ratione in tenetur id mollitia magnam optio voluptatum odio doloremque et provident minima soluta perspiciatis quis aliquam asperiores modi exercitationem. Iusto quis minima nemo dolor eligendi praesentium a quasi perferendis repellendus, nisi deleniti distinctio. Incidunt, eligendi perspiciatis cupiditate alias sapiente similique ex ut in officiis quod velit odit eius dicta, autem, facere quae placeat eos? Aliquam esse animi recusandae similique repellendus. Minima veritatis distinctio labore. Mollitia exercitationem voluptatem veritatis ut quis expedita corrupti dignissimos, provident officia non totam repellendus dolorem optio dolorum dicta nemo consequatur sunt nulla laudantium! Iste quisquam repudiandae voluptate quia possimus ab veritatis, praesentium in, at deleniti, ipsa accusantium obcaecati totam inventore eaque aspernatur consequuntur. Facilis eos mollitia facere aperiam saepe, deleniti recusandae, tempore doloribus, assumenda eveniet fugit itaque doloremque asperiores. Obcaecati voluptatibus repellendus voluptate at dolorum nostrum, quasi quidem cumque, ipsum assumenda voluptates architecto atque nesciunt consequuntur consectetur dicta perferendis ab. Dolore quam error illum doloremque, omnis maiores, rem laudantium dolorem eius harum consequuntur vero?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. Instead of `max-width` you have to use `min-width` to tell from what minimum width is required to display the sidebar.

And I also changed the JS code a little bit. For this you only need `toggle` to handle the click event nothing else.

```js
let toggleSideBarBtn = document.getElementById("toggleSideBarBtn")
toggleSideBarBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    let sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar")
    sidebar.classList.toggle("d-none");
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.containerMain {
    display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 0;
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
}


.togglesidebar {}

.bodyContainer {
    padding: 50px;
}

.d-none {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1231px) {
    .sidebar {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="containerMain">
        <div class="sidebarContainer">
            <button class="togglesidebar" id="toggleSideBarBtn">
                toggle
            </button>
            <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bodyContainer">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui dignissimos exercitationem temporibus quis
            tempore dolores debitis? Facere saepe, debitis aperiam eos dicta a architecto vitae maxime tempora veritatis
            quo voluptatibus amet sunt nihil perferendis ipsum reiciendis ipsam? Atque quia veniam possimus veritatis,
            dolores maiores eveniet quas eum ut, voluptatum, doloribus eos! Sit fugit magnam deleniti rem similique
            delectus. Reiciendis, dolorem? Qui vitae quibusdam iusto similique quos voluptatem dicta minus ea, hic esse
            fuga asperiores, consequuntur nihil. Temporibus ab veniam esse, cum fugit alias maiores quos hic rerum
            blanditiis accusamus magnam corporis nisi iure recusandae. Explicabo nulla nostrum dolorem dolorum adipisci
            natus suscipit cupiditate sunt magni eveniet delectus magnam repellat perferendis ipsum ab minus tempore
            doloremque amet neque voluptatibus provident sequi, deserunt beatae. Quae quod natus distinctio temporibus,
            veritatis, obcaecati harum nemo aspernatur modi provident libero quas dignissimos earum eligendi laudantium
            est quo perspiciatis sit nisi necessitatibus! Consectetur ducimus blanditiis quae nostrum omnis repellendus,
            ullam provident, modi, facilis exercitationem impedit corporis perspiciatis. Maiores quidem aliquam amet
            nulla sit debitis quo fugiat. Dolor, neque minima. Amet fugit nisi nulla consectetur, praesentium aspernatur
            ipsa possimus optio, illum, ducimus nihil esse dolores vitae laboriosam voluptatum? Veritatis dolor pariatur
            recusandae quisquam, neque corporis quidem doloremque numquam eius voluptatum! Reiciendis rem, fugit eum
            facere, voluptas fuga dolor mollitia saepe commodi sint eligendi dolore repellendus sunt necessitatibus
            minus? Voluptas, itaque culpa, aliquam nesciunt dicta exercitationem incidunt eveniet omnis harum est
            mollitia non eaque minima obcaecati ex fugiat ab architecto officiis doloremque! Optio ipsum, culpa maxime
            mollitia sapiente sequi nisi necessitatibus harum aut atque vel ullam totam quis ex vitae porro pariatur
            placeat itaque tenetur voluptatum explicabo autem delectus! Voluptatum perferendis suscipit fugit ea optio
            porro ratione. Officia exercitationem, voluptas nihil laudantium quidem rerum dignissimos iste amet non
            minima odio nesciunt tempore quam ullam accusamus eius dolore delectus ducimus? Alias eaque vitae sit
            blanditiis magnam earum, adipisci deserunt deleniti optio, quasi, est modi repellendus similique mollitia
            architecto sequi? Culpa praesentium exercitationem quisquam, ipsam, commodi sunt facere autem magni, aut
            architecto sequi veniam dignissimos. Possimus rerum, molestias dicta hic numquam, ratione in tenetur id
            mollitia magnam optio voluptatum odio doloremque et provident minima soluta perspiciatis quis aliquam
            asperiores modi exercitationem. Iusto quis minima nemo dolor eligendi praesentium a quasi perferendis
            repellendus, nisi deleniti distinctio. Incidunt, eligendi perspiciatis cupiditate alias sapiente similique
            ex ut in officiis quod velit odit eius dicta, autem, facere quae placeat eos? Aliquam esse animi recusandae
            similique repellendus. Minima veritatis distinctio labore. Mollitia exercitationem voluptatem veritatis ut
            quis expedita corrupti dignissimos, provident officia non totam repellendus dolorem optio dolorum dicta nemo
            consequatur sunt nulla laudantium! Iste quisquam repudiandae voluptate quia possimus ab veritatis,
            praesentium in, at deleniti, ipsa accusantium obcaecati totam inventore eaque aspernatur consequuntur.
            Facilis eos mollitia facere aperiam saepe, deleniti recusandae, tempore doloribus, assumenda eveniet fugit
            itaque doloremque asperiores. Obcaecati voluptatibus repellendus voluptate at dolorum nostrum, quasi quidem
            cumque, ipsum assumenda voluptates architecto atque nesciunt consequuntur consectetur dicta perferendis ab.
            Dolore quam error illum doloremque, omnis maiores, rem laudantium dolorem eius harum consequuntur vero?
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have time to answer take instead of hurry, you should read: [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: @MaxiGui Thanks for letting me know. Will always follow.